# html canvas return incorect imageData()

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to change current pixel's color to red, in styles I set canvas background-color to **grey**, but function `this.context.getImageData(actualX, actualY, 1, 1).data;` return this array [0,0,0,0] what's mean it is black, WHY ?

```
changeToRed(event: MouseEvent) {
    const left = this.canvasEl.offsetLeft;
    const top = this.canvasEl.offsetTop;

    const actualX = Math.floor(event.pageX - left);
    const actualY = Math.floor(event.pageY - top);

    const pixelData = this.context.getImageData(actualX, actualY, 1, 1);
    const data = pixelData.data;
    const color = `rgb(${data[0]},${data[1]},${data[2]},${data[3]})`;
    // I got color = rgb(0,0,0,0);

    this.userColor = color;

    pixelData.data[0] = 255;
    pixelData.data[1] = 0;
    pixelData.data[2] = 0;
    pixelData.data[3] = 0;

    this.context.putImageData(pixelData, actualX, actualY);
    // anyway it is colored in white, not in red
  }
```

Comment: Pixels with an alpha of 0 will have all other channels set to 0. This is standard behavior.

Comment: @Blindman67 do you have any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: There is nothing you can do. Pixels must have a non zero alpha. Even if you set alpha to a low value the pixel RGB is will be changed (pre multiplied alpha). To get the same RGB value back you need to have alpha near 255